# No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP

Tags: saml, spring-saml

Hi I am getting below exception while accessing SAML url. this primarily problem with the metadata_idp used. As this is working with other  IDP with different metadata. Please help me to find out the problem in metadata xml.

```
  javax.servlet.ServletException: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:161)
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:107)
```

My idpmetadat.xml configured is as below.

### idp.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
 ID="idfdmoAYqQtEozWEOcEj5IgJWhE1k" entityID="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/metadata">
 <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
   <CanonicalizationMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
   <ds:Reference URI="#idfdmoAYqQtEozWEOcEj5IgJWhE1k">
    <ds:Transforms>
     <ds:Transform
      Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">4UvquLeqvOeKQsO/e3XZdP7pGUE=
    </DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   fuisfhifhsfif
</SignatureValue>
  <ds:KeyInfo>
   <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
     
</ds:X509Certificate>
   </ds:X509Data>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
 <md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor ID="idWBVe5DrgqPvsjol4GsECxwBoARs"
  protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:AttributeService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap" />
  <md:AssertionIDRequestService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap" />
  <md:AssertionIDRequestService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:URI" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/assertion" />
 </md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor>
 <md:IDPSSODescriptor ID="id5dNezhGwQ3I1nafN2lvcCnG0hFg"
  protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:ArtifactResolutionService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap"
   index="0" isDefault="true" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/slo"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/slo_return" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/slo"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/slo_return" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/rni"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/rni_return" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/rni"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/rni_return" />
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
  </md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
  </md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:SingleSignOnService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sso" />
  <md:SingleSignOnService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sso" />
  <md:NameIDMappingService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/soap" />
 </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
 <md:SPSSODescriptor ID="idit9RFI3qQPIpRJhkjqQawKkdOMk"
  protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      gjvbdgjdbgjdbgjdgbjkdgbjkdgbjkdgbkdgb
</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:ArtifactResolutionService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spsoap"
   index="0" isDefault="true" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spslo"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spslo_return" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spsoap" />
  <md:SingleLogoutService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spslo"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spslo_return" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spsoap" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sprni"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sprni_return" />
  <md:ManageNameIDService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sprni"
   ResponseLocation="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/sprni_return" />
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
  </md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
  </md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:AssertionConsumerService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spassertion_consumer"
   index="2" />
  <md:AssertionConsumerService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spassertion_consumer"
   index="1" />
  <md:AssertionConsumerService
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
   Location="https://example.com/nidp/saml2/spassertion_consumer"
   index="0" isDefault="true" />
 </md:SPSSODescriptor>
 <md:Organization>
  <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">Preferred 
   Company</md:OrganizationName>
  <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">Preferred
     Company</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
  <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">www.bubu.com
  </md:OrganizationURL>
 </md:Organization>
 <md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
  <md:Company>  Company</md:Company>
  <md:GivenName>vawani</md:GivenName>
  <md:SurName>vawani</md:SurName>
  <md:EmailAddress>vawani@bubu.com</md:EmailAddress>
  <md:TelephoneNumber>xxxxxx</md:TelephoneNumber>
 </md:ContactPerson>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDP metadata is signed. Perhaps it's not imported due to failure during signature validation. If this is the case you can either re-configure Spring SAML to skip the signature validation, add the certificate used to sign metadata to your samlKeystore or simply remove the signature from the metadata xml.

Comment: Hi Vladi! As you said I have imported the certificate and set metadataTrustCheck to false, then it worked for me. But By doing this am I doing the signature validation with the response???